# Are questions about dynamic programming off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

First of all, there is the tag [dynamic-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming), which suggests that questions about dynamic programming are on-topic. On the other hand, if a specific question with this tag asks about help in formulation of a recurrence relation (or an explanation of the general approach) and the ultimate goal of the original poster is *not* implementation in actual code, is the question to be considered off-topic or not? If so, why?

Comment: In general, questions about dynamic programming are _not_ off-topic. If I have a question about implementing an Earley parser, that's clearly on topic. If the question is more of a theoretical CS question instead of an implementation question, then it's probably best asked on cs.SE instead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about dynamic *programming* are fine.  Emphasis on programming.  If you're asking about, say

> formulation of a recurrence relation (or an explanation of the general approach) and the ultimate goal of the original poster is *not* implementation in actual code

...then it's not really a programming question any more.  It's a computer science question.

Comment: When *programming* appears in the term *dynamic programming* (or *linear program* or *quadratic program*), it doesn't mean the same as *programming* in *computer programming*.  Which is why saying "emphasis on programming" makes no sense at all.  Questions about formal proofs of algorithmic complexity of a dynamic programming approach are 100% about dynamic programming... but off-topic.

Comment: @Ben: Call it an [abuse of terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation).